# Perfect matching in line graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am given a graph $T$ with an odd number greater than or equal to 3 of vertices.
Its line graph $L(T)$ has exactly one perfect matching.

I need to prove that if we remove any vertex from $T$, the number of even connected components in $T$ will be even.

I need an idea on how to start on this. How exactly does existence of the perfect matching in $L(T)$ influence the original graph?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Consider $T=3P_3$. It has an odd number (9) of vertices.

The line graph $L(T)=3P_2$, which has exactly one perfect matching.

Nevertheless, if you remove an endpoint $v$ from one of the paths in $T$ you are left with $T-v$ which has an odd number (1) of even components.

It is also not true if $T$ is connected. Consider the claw $K_{1,3}$ and subdivide each edge. Verify that it has an odd number of vertices and that its line graph has a unique perfect matching. Now if you remove the central vertex you are left with three components of size $2$.

Note: you can in fact prove that in this case, the number of even connected components after vertex removal is always odd. Maybe that was the intention of the question?

Comment: Sorry, does the statement hold if the graph is connected?

Comment: @mathnoob: I edited the answer to incorporate the reply to your question.